# Import data files in to a list based on a list of paths

Tags: r, list, csv

I have a load of .csv data files that are organised per category. I want to import them in to a list per category.

To do this, I've created a list of path files per category:

```
path_list <- list(a = c("path1","path2"), b= c("path3", "path4","path5"))
```

I then want read in the ".csv" files in to a new list that has the same structure as `path_list`:

```
data_list <- vector("list", length(path_list))

names(data_list) <- names(path_list)

for(i in 1:length(data_list)) { 
  for (j in 1:3)) {

  data_list[[i]] <- read.csv(path_list[[i]][[j]], header=T, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = F)

  print (i)

  }
}
```

This works for the first two elements of `path_list$a` but then I get the error:

```
Error in path_list[[i]][[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Which I know is because `j` only has two elements in a when actually `j` loops `1:3`. Is there a way of making `j` dynamic for each list element?

End result should look like:

```
data_list
$a
[1] "datafile1" "datafile2"

$b
[1] "datafile3" "datafile4" "datafile5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is out-of-bound because not all elements of `path_list` is a length-3 vector. The following works:

```
data_list <- setNames(vector("list", length(path_list)), names(path_list))
l <- lengths(path_list)    ## length of each vector

for(i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  tmp <- vector("list", l[i])
  for (j in 1:l[i])) {
     tmp[[j]] <- read.csv(path_list[[i]][j], header=TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     }
  data_list[[i]] <- tmp
  }
```